# Iterate over some pattern using shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-formatting, for

I have a file to process and get some entries from it. The file format is:

Example Input:

```
String1:"Hello"
String2:"World"
String3:"Question"
End
String1:"HelloAgain"
String5:"Answer"
End
String1:"NewEntry"
String2:"Foo"
String5:"NewFile"
End
```

Script will iterate and try to find String1 and print it, if String2 also present in that block append it to String1 and print.

Example Output:

```
Hello World
HelloAgain
NewEntry Foo
```

I need to loop through every such block.What I mean by a block here is content between every "End" string.
I have a script like:

```
    cat $1 | while read line
do
    if [[ $line == "String1="* ]];
    then
        string1=$line
    fi
    if [[ $line == "String2="* ]];
    then
        string2=$line
    fi
    if [[ $line == "End" ]];
    then
        if [ $string1 ];
            then
            echo "string1/"$string1"
        fi
        if [ $string1 ] && [ $string2 ];
            then
            echo $string1" "$string2
        fi
    #Reset values
    string1=''
    string2=''
    fi
done
```

This code works fine but the processing in between these blocks can become more complex, whats the best way to iterate such blocks and process those block entries.

NOTE:The file is kind of a property file.

Comment: I would like to extract pair of entries between two consecutive string "End" and do some processing on those entries iteratively.

Comment: Show example input _and_ example output please, so that we can see what your actual intent is, rather than a script that doesn't quite fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your provided input and requested output:

```
$ awk -F: '$0 == "End" { printf "\n" } $1 ~ /^String[12]$/ { gsub( /\"/, "", $2 ); printf( "%s ", $2)}' input
Hello World
HelloAgain
NewEntry Foo
```

Comment: This works phenomenal.Great!!!!!!! And if some of these lines doesn't have any of matching String then a blank line is printed. How do I avoid that?

Comment: I got it using sed '/^\s*$/d'.

Comment: this would print String2 lines even if String1 is not present in the block.  my reading of the Q is that String2 should only be printed if it is **also** in the block (i.e. as well as String1, but not if by itself).

Comment: also, you can avoid the need for `gsub()` if you use `-F':|"'` - and extract `$3` rather than `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F':|"' -lane 'if ($out && $_ eq "End") {print "$out"; $out=""};
  $out  = $F[2] if ($F[0] eq "String1");
  $out .= $F[2] if ($out && $F[0] eq "String2")' input.txt
```

This perl script uses either `:` or `"` as the field separator, to avoid the need to strip double-quotes from the output.  this means we need to extract the *third* field rather than the second as there is now an empty field between the first `:` and the `"`.  Perl arrays are zero-based, so that's `$F[2]`.

It only prints the output for a record ("block") if there is something to print, either String1 by itself **or** String1 and String2 are present - i.e. it doesn't print blank lines for non-matching records.

Here's the same algorithm in `awk`:

```
awk -F':|"' 'out && $0 == "End"  { print out; out="" };
  $1 == "String1" { out=$3 };
  out && $1 == "String2" { out = out$3 }' input.txt
```