# Performance comparison between log file processing

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I am processing large log files ~10GB of size and was using zgrep for pattern matching. But now the use case has become a bit complex and I can't use zgrep so I changed the logic to awk and this caused a lot of performance issue.

```
Time
using zgrep ~1.5 minutes
using awk ~11 minutes
using python ~ 13 minutes
```

I tried looking on google for possible solutions but couldn't find any.How can I efficiently parse .gz files?

Example Input

```
String1:"Hello"
String2:"World"
String3:"Question"
End
String1:"HelloAgain"
String5:"Answer"
End
String1:"NewEntry"
String2:"Foo"
String5:"NewFile"
End
```

Example Output

```
Hello World
HelloAgain
NewEntry Foo
```

This is the original question [Iterate over some pattern using shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382206/iterate-over-some-pattern-using-shell/382226#382226) .

Comment: `zcat file.gz|awk 'whatever you want to parse this file'`, also how use case become complex with `zgrep`please let us know what is your goal and what you want to achieve and give us a sample input data and your desired output

Comment: Yes I am using zcat and awk

Comment: Oh, sorry, then `zgrep infile.txt|awk -F: '$0 == "End" { printf "\n" } $1 ~ /^String[12]$/ { gsub( /\"/, "", $2 ); printf( "%s ", $2)}' input`, doesn't work?

Comment: How can zgrep work like this? But I tried, I couldn't get any result.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant `zcat infile.txt|awk -F: '$0 == "End" { printf "\n" } $1 ~ /^String[12]$/ { gsub( /\"/, "", $2 ); printf( "%s ", $2)}' input`

Comment: Yes I have done that as well.The awk performance figure is for that. Maybe the problem is with I/O and whatever I do performance will be compromised.

Comment: Can you show the zgrep and awk commands you used that have the 8x difference in execution time?

Comment: how does this compare for run time? `zcat input.gz | perl -F':|"' -lane  'if ($out && $_ eq "End") {print "$out"; $out=""}; $out=@F[2] if (m/^String1/) ; $out .= @F[2] if ($out && m/^String2/)'`.    BTW, the awk script can be optimised in the same way, to use `:` or `"` as the field separator, avoiding the need to use gsub.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Regarding zgrep: I only used zgrep "String1" file.gz, but the logic changed pointed here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382206/iterate-over-some-pattern-using-shell/382226#382226 and so used the command something like zcat infile.txt|awk -F: '$0 == "End" { printf "\n" } $1 ~ /^String[12]$/ { gsub( /\"/, "", $2 ); printf( "%s ", $2)}'. My point is zgrep was working for me because things were simple, but now the logic has grown complex and have to use awk for that.

Comment: @cas Well I can try this, but I just tried out java and got the same performance number similar to zgrep

Comment: I'm not sure about your input data, but how about if you use still `zgrep` as feeder to awk? like `zgrep . file.gz|awk ... `

Comment: @leo195 there's a better version in my answer to your previous question.  also the same thing implemented in awk (which should be faster because it doesn't use gsub).   Both my perl and awk versions use string comparisons rather than regexp matches, so that should be faster too....even the fastest regexp library is going to be slower than an `==` or `eq` comparison, which is not something that matters much on small files but can matter a lot on huge 10GB files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is pattern matching on individual lines, it's almost impossible to beat `grep` (or `zgrep` - which is basically just a fancier implementation of `zcat | grep`) for speed.  That's `grep`'s sole purpose, and it has been optimised over decades for exactly that task.

It's also the ONLY thing that `grep` can do.  Which is also part of the reason why it's so fast.

If you need to do more than that (e.g. output part of one line if it matches a pattern and optionally part of another line if the first condition is true and the second line matches a different pattern - as in your task) then that's a lot more complex, and beyond what `grep` can do.

That level of complexity is inherently slower than just a simple pattern match.  There's no avoiding that.  It's more work for the program to do, and it's always going to be more work.

That said, though, some languages are faster than others at particular things and, at least as importantly, the algorithm you choose to implement your task (i.e. how you choose to do it) can have an enormous impact on performance.

When processing small to medium-sized files, the performance difference is insignificant, probably not even noticable but when processing huge files (or when run repeatedly, many thousands of times) even small performance differences add up and make a very significant difference to the running time.

e.g. your original shell script would be abysmally slow compared to `awk` or `perl` or `python` (taking hours rather than minutes, at the very least) - that's because sh just isn't very good at those tasks.  looping over input data from a file in particular is very slow in sh.  The shell's primary purpose is for interactive and/or scripted job control, not to do complex text processing by itself (`bash` and `zsh` are a lot more capable than plain old `sh` in this regard, but a dedicated text processing language like `awk` or `perl` is always going to be better and faster).

In short:

- choose the best tool for the job
- implement a good, fast algorithm.

BTW, "best" is not only the tool best-suited to the job but also partly the one you know best, and how easy it's going to be do write what you need in that language.  e.g. for many tasks, `awk` and `perl` have roughly similar performance (`awk` is typically a bit faster, but `perl` has a lot more built-in functions AND a huge library of code to do almost anything you can think of, called [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/)).  If you know awk better than perl, than use awk.  and vice-versa.

I tend to use awk for simpler jobs and perl for more complex ones.  sometimes I use python, but most of the things I write are more suited to perl than python and I know perl a lot better than I know python.

Comment: I totally agree with your answer and your suggestion of using string matching rather than regexp improved the performance.And what I have found here and from my analysis for this particular problem is Java and only zgrep are most efficient then awk and then python. I didn't try perl though.Also using zcat file.gz | awk is slower than zgrep . file.gz | awk as suggested by  @AFSHIN

Comment: I actually find it hard to believe that java could be faster than awk at the same text-processing job.  i suppose it's possible, but are they running the same basic algorithm?

Comment: Yes the same algorithm I trimmed the algo to the base minimum to check the performance and got the difference. Also Java used BufferedReader so I wondered maybe thats the reason and optimizing I/O in some way but awk+zgrep should be doing that as well, thats my assumption though.

Comment: if buffering helps, it would be interesting to see how my perl one-liner compares.  it might also be worthwhile doing some googling about awk input buffering.

Comment: Python can read compressed files directly which does speed up the processing time.

Comment: yeah, perl can too, e.g. with `IO::Uncompress::AnyUncompress` - supports gzip, zip, bzip2, and lzop.